# Java BasicResponseHandler exception

Tags: java, httpresponse

I try to consume an API and I get a response 409. The docs say that I have to read the body to build a resolution. However, when I run this:

```
String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
```

> org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Conflict
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractResponseHandler.handleResponse(AbstractResponseHandler.java:69)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:65)
>       at commlayer.Uploader$FileUploader.chunkRequest(Uploader.java:844)
>       at commlayer.Uploader$FileUploader.(Uploader.java:786)
>       at commlayer.Uploader.startUpload(Uploader.java:530)
>       at commlayer.Uploader.main(Uploader.java:152)

How can I extract the content to get the required information?

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting a string/json response, try this.

`HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
System.out.println(responseString);`

More info is needed though.